# Troubles with dynamically adding and removing data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize, custom-data-attribute

I'm building a parallax page that I'm running into an issue when resizing the browser. I'm controlling my animations with data attributes, which look like this:

```
<div class="element" data-0="transform:translateY(0px)" data-1283="transform:translateY(-1283 px)"></div>
```

This will do an animation that moves the element up the page by 1283px and take 1283px of scrolling to complete. I'm am adding the code with jquery like this:

```
$element.attr('data-0', 'transform:translateY(0px)').attr('data-' + windowHeight, 'transform:translateY(-' + windowHeight + ' px)');
```

The problem I'm having is that when the window is resized, my animation amount also needs to change. I'm running a function on window resize to look for and remove any data attributes:

```
$('.element').each( function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  $.each( $element.data(), function( key ) {
    $element.removeAttr( 'data-' + key );
  });
});
```

Then I'm calling my function that adds the data attributes. I also have a setTimeout function built so it only calls this function after the window is done being resized. This works great the first time I resize the window but anytime after that, jquery is not finding any elements with data attributes. Is there any reason why it would find them the first time but not anytime after that?

Comment: Use `removeData()`, not `removeAttr()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are adding data attributes incorrectly.

```
$element.attr('data-0', 'transform:translateY(0px)')
```

Instead, do the following.

```
$element.data('0', 'transform:translateY(0px)')
```

jQuery doesn't *realize* that you added a "data" attribute with your first method - it just knows you added "an" attribute. When jQuery first parses your DOM, it recognizes all `data-*` attributes as `data` and keeps reference to them, thus why your code works the first time around.

Comment: I need the data attributes to be html5. Which is why I was using .attr()

Comment: @user2339729 That doesn't make any sense. If you don't want to use `.data()`, then don't use it. If you are going to use it, then use the associated methods to get and set it.

Comment: If I used .data(), wouldn't it just be stored data information within jquery instead of an actual data attribute inline on the html element?

Comment: @user2339729 What difference does that make? Are there 3rd party scripts parsing your DOM for updated `data-*` attributes? If not, then it doesn't make a difference *how* you store/retrieve data associated with elements.

Comment: Yes, the plugin I'm using for the animation checks for the html5 data attribute, not the stored jquery data.

Comment: Ok, so, don't use `data()` to retrieve the data then. Or set it using `attr()` *and* `data()`

Comment: So, I guess that is the issue. I can't figure out how to change my function that looks for the data to work with attr().

Comment: Also, I don't understand why my function does work to remove them the first time you resize the window, but not the second. I'm adding them the same way on load and on resize.